# Term for 'Action' that evokes idea of robots

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for *action* or *task* that would be associated with a robot. For example in context:

> The robot should perform a(n) _________ if circumstances allow.

This word will be used alone, out of context of robotics and hopefully will remind the reader of robots. I am willing to accept there is no such word if that is the case.

Comment: Sounds like a *mechanical task*.

Comment: I like the idea of task... I'm open to more ideas in that vein

Comment: If you're looking for an array of ideas, that invites well meaning opinions, not definitive answers, and those are not the ideal arrangement on this site.

Comment: No I definitely need a single word. I meant that synonyms of task as well as action are acceptable.

Comment: Can you say what limits you to one word? A question of setting, not of trusting your absolute need.

Comment: This will be used in a program I am developing. The overall theme is robotics/automation, and this word will be used to refer to an action the application should perform. I prefer not to use 'Action' because a similar application uses the same word in a similar context.

Comment: ...perform an activity?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from experience as a software developer, the most common noun used in this context is [**task**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/task). It is the most generically used noun for "a job that needs to be done" (it equally applies for human work)

> [**Task**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/task)
>
> A piece of work to be done or undertaken.
> *‘a new manager was given the task of developing the club's talent’*

However, there are other nouns that you can use, though their meaning is subtly different.

- [**Algorithm**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/algorithm) - This focuses on the robot's **pre-programmed behavior**, which is a complex logical evaluation. Another synonym with a similar meaning is [**process**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/process).
- [**Command**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/command) - This focuses more on **a human giving the robot a task**. Another synonym with a similar meaning is [**instruction**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/instruction).

*In a somewhat archaic context of programming, instruction could also mean "a single line of code" or "a single operation", which is closer to "algorithm" than it is to "command". However, this is no longer used in modern day programming. "Instruction" is now commonly understood to be synonymous with "command".*

[**Task**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/task), however, applies to both meanings. So I would again advise to use "task", because it applies in both cases and therefore accurately encapsulates the entire process that spans from *issuing the command* up to *doing the work*.

---

**Edit** - a comment of yours:

> This will be used in a program I am developing. The overall theme is robotics/automation, and this word will be used to refer to an action the application should perform. I prefer not to use 'Action' because a similar application uses the same word in a similar context.

If this is the context in which you want to use it, I would also advise against the use of "task", as there is already something going by that name (an asynchronously executed method).
The same applies to "process". It is a well established term in programming and will therefore confuse developers between *your meaning* and *the commonly understood meaning*.

In this context, I would suggest "**instruction**". Out of all the options I listed, it is the only one that is not actively in use anymore in the field of programming (unless you build processors for a living, which seems well out of scope)

From an **English** perspective, I stand by my answer that "task" is the best word. But not from a **programming** perspective, due to established definitions.

Comment: This word will mainly be user-side, so I'm not quite so worried about the concerns you raise.

Answer (score 1):

A robot is tasked to perform a function, but that is not what you are referring to. You want to know how to perform it. In automation, function/tasks are subdivided into *moves* and further into *paths*.

Function: Assemble doodad into doohickey

Task: Pick up doodad

Move: Move to doodad basket

Path: XYZ -> XYZ

Collaborative robots behave in the exact way you are describing. The bot attempts to perform a function/task, which is a series of *moves*. However, if it detects an obstacle in its *path*, say a person, it is prohibited from continuing.

> The robot should perform **the next move** if circumstances allow.
>
> The robot should **traverse the next path** if circumstances allow.

http://blog.robotiq.com/what-does-collaborative-robot-mean

Answer (score 1):

The robot should perform a **routine** if circumstances allow.

> **[routine](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/routine)**
>
> noun UK ​ /ruːˈtiːn/ US ​ /ruːˈtiːn/
>
> [C or U] a usual or fixed way of doing things:
> *There's no set/fixed routine at work - every day is different.*
> He checks under the car for bombs as a matter of routine.
> ​>
>
> [ C ] a regular series of movements, jokes, or similar things used in a performance:
> *an exercise/dance routine*
> *He went into his usual "I'm the head of the family" routine (= usual way of speaking).*
> ​>
>
> [ C ] specialized computing a part of a computer program that does a particular operation